# UIActivityViewController -- NSURL ActivityItemProvider default thumbnail

Tags: thumbnails, nsurl, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to figure out what sets the default thumbnail under the paperclip (instead of the embossed Safari icon) when you use an NSURL to attach a link in a UIActivityViewController. I feel like I have seen websites such as google and the itunes store setting these thumbnails to be helpful images. I feel that the embossed safari icon is too vague and the user doesn't know what link he/she is sending.

Is it perhaps something in the html headers for that link?

Thanks!

[image: vague safari icon]

Answer (score 3):

I had to decypher all the `UIActivityViewController` documentation recently. You probably don't want to include a `UIImage` with your `NSURL` in blind hopes it will be used as a thumbnail. As I understand, you can't be sure what the `UIActivity` will do with the image, it might post that instead of the URL.

In your activityItems array parameter to `initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:`, instead of the `NSURL`, pass an object you create conforming to the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol. You can have whatever controller is opening the `UIActivityViewController` be the object that conforms to this protocol, for example, in which case your activityItems parameter would be `@[self]`.

In addition to implementing the 2 required methods `activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:` and `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:` to both just return your `NSURL`, also implement this one to return whatever thumbnail image you like:

```
- (UIImage *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController thumbnailImageForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType suggestedSize:(CGSize)size;
```

Note one thing that isn't really spelled out in the documentation, if you really need to have multiple objects in your activityItems array and are updating it to use `UIActivityItemSource` (or `UIActivityItemProvider`) objects, then it needs a separate such object to return each of the original data objects in your original array. For example, if your data items are an `NSURL` and a `UIImage` then make one `UIActivityItemSource` to return the `NSURL` and another to return the `UIImage`. Having one `UIActivityItemSource` that returns an array of `NSURL` and `UIImage` like your original activityItems array does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the activityImage property of the derived UIActivity object to the image you want to displayed under the paperclip?

"
For UIActivityTypePostToTwitter:
The object posts the provided content to the user’s Twitter feed. When using this service, you can provide NSString, NSAttributedString, UIImage, AVAsset, and NSURL objects as data for the activity items. You may also specify NSURL objects whose contents use the assets-library scheme."

Note the UIImage object that you can include in the array that get passed into the UIActivityViewController.  This link describes more on the activityImage property, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActivity/activityType.

Kevin